# NSOperation + setCompletionBlock

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have few different questions about `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue` and I know guys that yours answers will help me;

I have to load a big amount of images and I have created my own loader based on `NSOperation`, `NSOperationQueue` and `NSURLConnection` (asynchronous loading);

Questions:

1. If I set `maxConcurrentOperationCount` (for example 3) for queue (`NSOperationQueue`), does it mean that only 3 operations performed in the same time even queue has 100 operations?
2. When I set property `maxConcurrentOperationCount` for queue sometimes "`setCompletionBlock`" doesn't work and count (`operationCount`) only increases; Why?

MyLoader:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _loadingFiles = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        _downloadQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
        _downloadQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 3;
        _downloadQueue.name = @"LOADER QUEUE";

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)loadFile:(NSString *)fileServerUrl handler:(GetFileDataHandler)handler {
    if (fileServerUrl.length == 0) {
        return;
    }

    if ([_loadingFiles objectForKey:fileServerUrl] == nil) {
        [_loadingFiles setObject:fileServerUrl forKey:fileServerUrl];

        __weak NSMutableDictionary *_loadingFiles_ = _loadingFiles;
        MyLoadOperation *operation = [MyLoadOperation new];
        [operation fileServerUrl:fileServerUrl handler:^(NSData *fileData) {
            [_loadingFiles_ removeObjectForKey:fileServerUrl];
            if (fileData != nil) {
                handler(fileData);
            }
        }];
        [operation setQueuePriority:NSOperationQueuePriorityLow];
        [_downloadQueue addOperation:operation];

        __weak NSOperationQueue *_downloadQueue_ = _downloadQueue;
        [operation setCompletionBlock:^{
            NSLog(@"completion block :%i", _downloadQueue_.operationCount);
        }];
    }
}
```

MyOperation:

```
@interface MyLoadOperation()
@property (nonatomic, assign, getter=isOperationStarted) BOOL operationStarted;

@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString *fileServerUrl;

@property(nonatomic, copy)void (^OnFinishLoading)(NSData *);

@end
@implementation MyLoadOperation
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _executing = NO;
        _finished = NO;
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)fileServerUrl:(NSString *)fileServerUrl
              handler:(void(^)(NSData *))handler {

    @autoreleasepool {

        self.fileServerUrl = fileServerUrl;

        [self setOnFinishLoading:^(NSData *loadData) {
            handler(loadData);
        }];

        [self setOnFailedLoading:^{
            handler(nil);
        }];
        self.url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:self.fileServerUrl];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
                                        initWithURL:self.url
                                        cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                        timeoutInterval:25];
        [request setValue:@"" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];

        self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];

        [self.connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
        [self.connection start];
        _data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    }
}
- (void)main {
    @autoreleasepool {
        [self stop];
    }
}
- (void)start {
    [self setOperationStarted:YES];

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    _finished = NO;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    if ([self isCancelled])
    {
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
        _finished = YES;
        _executing = NO;
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    }
    else
    {
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
        _finished = NO;
        _executing = YES;
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    }
}

- (BOOL)isConcurrent {

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)isExecuting {
    return _executing;
}

- (BOOL)isFinished {

    return _finished;
}

- (void)cancel {
    [self.connection cancel];
    if ([self isExecuting])
    {
        [self stop];
    }
    [super cancel];
}
#pragma mark -NSURLConnectionDelegate
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [_data appendData:data];
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    if ([self OnFinishLoading]) {
        [self OnFinishLoading](_data);
    }
    if (![self isCancelled]) {
        [self stop];

    }
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
;
    if (![self isCancelled]) {
        [self stop];
    }
}
- (void)stop {
    @try {
        __weak MyLoadOperation *self_ = self;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self_ completeOperation];
        });
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception! %@", exception);
        [self completeOperation];
    }
}
- (void)completeOperation {
    if (![self isOperationStarted]) return;

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    _executing = NO;
    _finished  = YES;

    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
}
```

Comment: To be clear, are you saying that when using `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of 3, you're seeing all 100 of your operations run and complete (not just the first three), but not seeing `operationCount` not change at all? The `operationCount` method is not entirely reliable (see documentation for that method), but you should see some movement in the value returned. Can you describe the behavior in a little more detail?

Comment: Thank you for answer; Yes, you are right, I have to describe the behavior a little better; Look, if I remove `maxConcurrentOperationCount` everything works fine with code that I have shown above; Fine - I mean `setCompletionBlock` invoke every time and `operationCount` decrease; If I use `maxConcurrentOperationCount`(number doesn't matter)`setCompletionBlock` invoke but very often it stops work when I scroll `tableview`(where I display my loading images); In other words I change only one line and code changes behavior;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must start the connection in the Operation's `start` method, and not in `fileServerUrl:handler:`.

I would remove this method altogether, and only provide an init method with all required parameters where you can completely setup the operation. Then, in method `start` start the connection.

Additionally, it's not clear why you override `main`.

Modifying the state variables `_executing` and `_finished` could be more concise and more clear (you don't need to set them initially, since the are already initialized to `NO`). Only set them in the "final" method `completeOperation` including KVO notifications.

You also do not need a @try/@catch in `stop`, since function `dispatch_async()`  does not throw Objective-C exceptions.

Your `cancel` method is not thread safe, and there are also a few other issues. I would suggest the following changes:

```
@implementation MyOperation {
    BOOL _executing;
    BOOL _finished;

    NSError* _error;  // remember the error
    id _result;       // the "result" of the connection, unless failed
    completion_block_t _completionHandler; //(your own completion handler)
    id _self; // strong reference to self
}

// Use the "main thread" as the "synchronization queue"

- (void) start
{
    // Ensure start will be called only *once*:
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (!self.isCancelled && !_finished && !_executing) {

            [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
            _executing = YES;
            [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
            _self = self; // keep a strong reference to self in order to make 
                          // the operation "immortal for the duration of the task

            // Setup connection:
            ...

            [self.connection start];
        }
    });
}

- (void) cancel 
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue, ^{
        [super cancel];
        [self.connection cancel];
        if (!_finished && !_executing) {
            // if the op has been cancelled before we started the connection
            // ensure the op will be orderly terminated:
            self.error = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:@"MyOperation"
                                                    code:-1000
                                                userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: @"cancelled"}];
            [self completeOperation];
        }
    });
}


- (void)completeOperation 
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    self.isExecuting = NO;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    self.isFinished = YES;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];

    completion_block_t completionHandler = _completionHandler;
    _completionHandler = nil;
    id result = self.result;
    NSError* error = self.error;
    _self = nil;
    if (completionHandler) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
            completionHandler(result, error);
        });
    }
}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    if ([self onFinishLoading]) {
        [self onFinishLoading](self.result);
    }
    [self completeOperation];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if (self.error == nil) {
        self.error = error;
    }
    [self completeOperation];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer; You have gave me very useful advices; Unfortunately, now the biggest problem is that I can not stop execution of operation. In other words method `cancel` never invokes; I don't understand reason;

Comment: @O.Daniel Please set a breakpoint into the first line of the cancel method, and a second into the block - executing on the main thread. Do you hit the first breakpoint? If this is the case, but you never got into the block, then the main thread is possibly blocked.

Comment: Look, I have `_downloadQueue` where I added all operations during loading process; Sometimes I have to stop the process and remove all operations from `_downloadQueue`. I do next - `[_downloadQueue cancelAllOperations];`but It doesn't work and all operations continue working; And answer for your question is no, neither of two breakpoints hit;

Comment: @O.Daniel `cancelAllOperations` sends a cancel message to all operations currently in the queue. So, there is something odd with your code. Ensure also that `_downloadQueue` is not nil, and that your NSOperation subclass is properly subclassed.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your questions:

1. Yes, a `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of three means that only three will run at a time. Doing network requests like this is perfect example of when you'd want to use `maxConcurrentOperationCount`, because failure to do so would result in too many network requests trying to run, most likely resulting in some of the connections failing when using a slower network connection.
2. The main issue here, though, is that you're calling your operation's `fileServerUrl` method (which is starting the connection) from `MyLoader`. You've disconnected the request from the operation's `start` (defeating the purpose of `maxConcurrentCount` of `3` and possibly confusing the state of the operation).

   The `start` method should be initiating the connection (i.e. don't start the request until one of those three available concurrent operations is available). Furthermore, since you cannot pass the URL and the `handler` to the `start` method, you should move your logic that saves those values to a customized rendition of your `init` method.

There are other minor edits we might suggest to your operation (`main` not needed, `operationStarted` is a little redundant, simplify the `_executing`/`_finished` handling, etc.), but the starting of the connection in `fileServerUrl` rather than being initiated by the `start` method is the key issue.

Thus:

```
- (id)initWithServerUrl:(NSString *)fileServerUrl
                handler:(void(^)(NSData *))handler
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _executing = NO;
        _finished = NO;

        // do your saving of `fileServerURL` and `handler` here, e.g.

        self.fileServerUrl = fileServerUrl;

        self.OnFinishLoading:^(NSData *loadData) {
            handler(loadData);
        }];

        [self setOnFailedLoading:^{
            handler(nil);
        }];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)startRequest {
    self.url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:self.fileServerUrl];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:self.url
                                                                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                                            timeoutInterval:25];
    [request setValue:@"" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];

    self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];

    [self.connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    [self.connection start];
    _data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)start {
    if ([self isCancelled])
    {
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
        _finished = YES;
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];

        return;
    }

    [self setOperationStarted:YES];  // personally, I'd retire this and just reference your `executing` flag, but I'll keep it here for compatibility with the rest of your code

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    _executing = YES;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];

    [self startRequest];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, the answer is yes, if set 3 as a max number of operations, only 3 can be running togheter.
The second is bit strange problem and I'm not totally sure that this answer will be correct.
 When you leave operations to an NSOperationQueue, you can't be sure on which thread they will be executed, this lead a huge problem with async connection.
 When you start an NSURLConnection as usual you receive the delegate callbacks without a problem, that is because the connection is running on a thread with a living run loop. If you start the connection on a secondary thread, callbacks will be called on that thread, but if you don't keep the run loop alive they will be never received.
*That's where probably my answer isn't correct, GCD should take care of living run loops, because GCD queues runs on living threads.* 
But if not, the problem could be that operations are started on a different thread, the start method is called, but the callbacks are never called. Try to check if the thread is always the main thread.

Comment: The OP is scheduling the `NSURLConnection` delegates on `[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]`, which solves the issue you describe. I think the problem rests elsewhere.